# Why does excel create multiple ranges for a data model Pivot? And how to consolidate or prevent this from happening?

Tags: excel, pivot, range, datamodel

Below is the issue I am facing and would like to have only 1 range for all the pivots.
Is there any easy way to prevent this from happening and how to fix it?

[Multiple ranges created by excel for a datamodel pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j669N.png)

Comment: Those are all the tables loaded to the data model, either by you or by someone else.

Comment: How do I consolidate it or have everything reference to just 1 range/table

Comment: Those are all separate tables. If. you only wanted one table loaded, you can delete them in the data model using the Power Pivot window.